# Tkinter widgets all pack in the same Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to make a fairly simple GUI with multiple windows. I have my windows built as classes just with a label in each one for now. I can't seem to figure out why when I run my program it packs all of the labels on the "StartPage" and none of the other windows have anything in them. It could be that I have my classes configured incorrectly?

```
import tkinter as tk


class application(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'both', expand = True)

    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, WeeklyBudget, LongtermSavings, Investments):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


    self.ShowFrame(StartPage)

def ShowFrame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        start_label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Welcome to Finance Track!')
        start_label.pack()
        week_btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Weekly Budgeting', command =lambda: controller.ShowFrame(WeeklyBudget))
    savings_btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Longterm Savings', command = lambda: controller.ShowFrame(LongtermSavings))
    invest_btn = tk.Button(self, text = 'Investments', command = lambda: controller.ShowFrame(Investments))


    week_btn.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
    savings_btn.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
    invest_btn.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

class WeeklyBudget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(text = 'Welcome to your Weekly Budget')
        label.pack()
        add_btn = tk.Button(text = 'add new week')
        add_btn.pack()

class LongtermSavings(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(text = 'Welcome to your Longterm Savings')

        label.pack()

class Investments(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(text = 'Welcome to your Investments')
        label.pack()

app = application()
app.mainloop()
```

The current outcome as I described earlier is just one window with all the labels and all the buttons in it.

Comment: Most of your widgets are not being explicitly given a parent (the first positional parameter).  The default parent is the root window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jasonharper mention you aren't defining the parents (aka master) of many widgets.

```py
class Investments(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(text = 'Welcome to your Investments')
        label.pack()
```

Using this `Investments` class for example, your label will be given the window as it's parents by default, to set it's parent to the newly created frame, just do the following:

```py
class Investments(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = 'Welcome to your Investments')
        label.pack()
```